# Use PowerApps If command to manage the text of a label

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field, powerapp, if-condition, single-line-of-text

I'm trying to achieve something easy but I'm new to PowerApps and is way different than InfoPath.

I want to configure a text label to show different text based of values of other field.

For Example:

In my form I have a Choise field with Choises: Choise1, Choise2, Choise3.

When `Choise1` is selected from end users I want the text label to show a specific text like `CustomText1` or `CustomText2`.

I tried to add If in the text value of the label but it doesn't work. I use this as I did in a training:

```
If(ThisItem.'DataCardValue2'.Value="Choise1","CustomText1"," No selection")
```

`DataCardValue2` is the Choice field I want to evaluate.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using a blank layout while developing powerapp or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are using **Label** show the text based on selection in drop-down.

In that case you need to set the **Text** property of your **Label** field based on the value of your field **Choise**.

To check the value of `Choise` is equal to "Choise1" or not, you need to use **[IF function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if)**.

You need to use your formula in **Text** property of Label field something like below:

```
IF(DataCardValue2.Text = "Choise1","CustomText1","No selection")
```

**Note**: I have used `DataCardValue2.Text` and `DataCardValue2.Value`.